# A function is Lipchitz iff his absolute value is Lipchitz?

Tags: calculus

I would like to know if this assertion is true:

A function is Lipchitz iff his absolute value is Lipchitz?

I succes to prove that if the function is Lipchitz then the absolute value is Lipchitz

but for the other direction I don't know if is it true
(This is not a homework)

I will be grateful if someone could help me .

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f(x)=1$ for $x$ rational and $-1$ for $x$ irrational then $|f|$ is Lipschitz but $f$ is not.